# Why do all fifth generation fighters (J20, F22, SU57) use Trapezoid wings?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, fighter

It seems that trapezoid wings are used by all fifth generation fighters (although the wing of J20 looks quite like delta wing), but why? What made a trapezoid wing so attractive? Why don't they use other forms, like the swept wing on SU27?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trapezoidal wings have advantages and disadvantages:

- Better performance than delta wings at transonic speed
- Good stealth performances
- Flaps can be easily used.
- drag reducing
- better Lift/Drag ratio than delta wings

The problem is that they stall at much lower angles of attack than delta wings.

Edit:this problem is overcome using leading edge,LERX,and/or canards

Comment: I’ve edited your question a bit.  If I accidentally removed something important, feel free to edit or revert to the original.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But can you compare the trapezoid wing with the swept wing(like ones on SU27) ?

Comment: what is biscus drag?

Comment: drag caused by layers of the fluid sticking to the object.More surface area means more of the object is in contact with the fluid, which means more drag

Comment: possible typo in above comments -- the word is "viscous"

Comment: Yes it's viscous drag....(because of automatic corrector)